# How to configure FreeBSD to run headless without hitting high interrupt rates?

Tags: freebsd, video, bios, interrupt, netbsd

When running headless (without monitor, keyboard, mouse attached) FreeBSD versions 8.2, 8.3, 9.0 and NetBSD version 5.0 has known issues ([FreeBSD PR 156596](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/query-pr.cgi?pr=156596), [NetBSD 46596](http://mail-index.netbsd.org/netbsd-bugs/2013/09/17/msg034280.html)) to generate extremely high interrupt rates. The issue is also known as an interrupt storm and happens when PCI interrupts are shared. Often EHCI is on the same interrupt (#16, irq16) as VGAPCI. Other users reported to have success by [attaching a PS/2 keyboard](https://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=71589.0).

The Intel NUC DC3217BY BIOS has no option to disable the onboard video/GPU. We don't need VGA output (headless operation). We do need USB: the boot drive (SDHC card) is attached via a USB bridge.

How can FreeBSD configured to not hit the high interrupts rates, or limit the interrupt rate on ehci0?
For example how to **disable VGA irq assignment** in FreeBSD?

Comment: Then follow up the reported bugs... we are very unlikely to give better answers than the experts in charge.

Comment: The reported bugs don't supply a solution, neither a software workaround. A workaround for us could be to limit the interrupt rate on ehci0 or even disable ehci0 completely in FreeBSD.

Comment: If you're considering workarounds: would attaching a dummy VGA plug help?